# Hive QL Declaration

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, hiveql

What is the difference between CHAR() and VARCHAR() declarations from HQL?

Comment: VARCHAR is variable length, while CHAR is fixed length. Simple googling would give you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VARCHAR holds the advantage since variable-length data would produce smaller rows and, thus, smaller physical files.

CHAR fields require less string manipulation because of fixed field widths. Partiton, lookup, join, group on CHAR field are faster than VARCHAR fields.

Answer (score 0):

like in any other language:

- `CHAR` is fixed length character datatype , for example If you define char(10) and the input value is of 6 characters then the remaining 4 will be filled with spaces.
- `VARCHAR` has variable length, for example If you define varchar(10) and the input value is of 6 characters then only 6 bytes will be used and no additional space will be blocked.

[HIVE DOC REFERENCE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-VarcharvarcharVarchar)